# Build-dependencies for psycopg2 could not be satisfied

Tags: django, python-2.7, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to install psycopg2 in order to connect django database with postgresql. I tried command:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep psycopg2
```

but it throws error

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpq-dev : Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: comerr-dev but it is not going to be installed
python-all-dbg : Depends: python (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
              Depends: python-all (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python-dbg (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2) but it is not going to be installed
python-all-dev : Depends: python (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
              Depends: python-all (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python-dev (= 2.7.3-0ubuntu2.2) but 2.7.3-0ubuntu7.1 is to be installed
python3-all-dbg : Depends: python3 (= 3.2.3-0ubuntu1.2) but 3.2.3-5ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
               Depends: python3-all (= 3.2.3-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-dbg (= 3.2.3-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3.2-dbg but it is not going to be installed
python3-all-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.2.3-0ubuntu1.2) but 3.2.3-5ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
               Depends: python3-all (= 3.2.3-0ubuntu1.2) but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: python3-dev (= 3.2.3-0ubuntu1.2) but 3.2.3-5ubuntu1.2 is to be installed
E: Build-dependencies for psycopg2 could not be satisfied.
```

Although the following requirements are satisfied means I have installed the following

```
Python 2.7
Python 3.4
PostgreSQL versions 9.1
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you are using `apt-get build-dep` and not `apt-get install`. The following command should be enough to use Django with PostgreSQL.

```
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```

Then install psycopg2 using apt-get or pip in your virtual env.

Comment: yum install postgresql-libs in RPM land